# What is the l2-norm of a scalar

Tags: clustering, loss-function, gan, regularization, distance

What is the meaning of the l2-norm when dealing with scalar values? I'm assuming it would be the same thing as taking the absolute value.

For context: I am trying to implement the clustering method presented in the following paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.11832 where I stumbled across the following loss function:

$$
L_{E,G}(\phi(t),\theta(t)) = ||x-\hat{x}||_2^2+\lambda||C_\psi(\hat{x}_a)||_2^2
$$

where E and G are neural networks parameterized by $\phi$ and $\theta$, respectively. These are set up as an autoencoder. C is another neural network parameterized by $\psi$ with a role similar to a discriminator which only outputs values in the interval $[0,1]$. The overall structure presented in the paper is the following:
[image]

The loss for network C is defined as
$$
L_C(\psi(t)) = ||C_\psi(\hat{x}_a)-\alpha||_2^2+||C_\psi(\gamma x+(1-\gamma)\hat{x})||_2^2
$$

My current implementation does not result in the expected results and I am now wondering whether the reason could be that I have misunderstood what the l2-norm in the loss functions above is supposed to do.